# Optimize Custom Adapter in Listview Android

Tags: android, listview, custom-adapter

I am working on a chat application. I have a listview in my chat room with number of views in it. On the basis of some conditions, I change the visibility of views.
As if received message will have different view, sender will have different view. Received message with image will have another view and so on.
The problem is that it takes a lot of time to set adapter, which is showing a huge delay. 
I think may be I am doing something wrong in holder. If any one could provide a better solution, will be a great help!

```
    @Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Chat_Holder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                R.layout.chat_item, parent, false);

        holder = new Chat_Holder(view);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder= (Chat_Holder) view.getTag();
    }
    //setting views on the basis of conditions 
    // list the arraylist of model type, in which isSender is a boolean variable
    if(list.get(position).isSender){
      holder.sender.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      holder.reciever.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      //set text
    }
    else{
      holder.sender.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      holder.reciever.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     }
    return view;
   }
```

Chat_Holder contains a lots of ids for my each textview and Imageview and LinearLayout. It would be difficult to make it understand. But I think I have realized my flaws. Kindly confirm me if I am wrong.

I have a xml layout file. chat_item. In this I have different layouts for each of my condition.

```
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/lay_reciever_text"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >
        //contains textview and imageview for dp
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/lay_reciever_text_image"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >
        //contains textview and imageviews for dp and image
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/lay_sender_text"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >
         //contains textview and imageview for dp
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/lay_sender_text_image"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal" >
         //contains textview and imageviews for dp and image
    </LinearLayout>
```

And I think this is a bad approach. Else should I use different layouts for each of my condition like:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final Chat_Holder holder;
    int view_type=0;
    if (view == null) {
         if(list.get(position).isSender){
            if(list.get(position).hasImage){
              view_type=1;
              view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                 R.layout.chat_item_sender_image, parent, false);
             }
            else{
               view_type=2;
               view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                 R.layout.chat_item_sender_text, parent, false);
             }
         }
         else{
            if(list.get(position).hasImage){
              view_type=3;
              view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                 R.layout.chat_item_reciever_image, parent, false);
             }
            else{
               view_type=4;
               view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
                 R.layout.chat_item_reciever_text, parent, false);
             }
         }
        holder = new Chat_Holder(view, view_type);

        view.setTag(holder);
    }
    else{
        holder= (Chat_Holder) view.getTag();
    }
    //setting texts on the basis of conditions 

    return view;
   }
```

Which one should I adopt? OR anything else? I am badly stuck in it.

Comment: You have to follow [this](https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Android-Speech-Bubble) link. Change 9 patch png images according to your need.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. But this is not what I want. It's something like watsapp. In which not only the background of item is to be changed but also the text alignment and visibility of a view if image is also attached.

Comment: Difficult to see what's happening because you're using fields but haven't included the whole class. What is `list`, `sender`, `receiver`? In the general case, you'll want to implement multiple view types so that you don't need to show/hide the views, but instead ListView will ensure you only get given the correct view.

Comment: sender, receiver are the name of the layouts, contained in holder. Sorry I forgot to write holder.sender and holder.receiver. Do u mean to say that I should inflate different layouts for each of my condition? Like if I am checking that the message is received and contains an image so I should inflate one view. If the message is with a video, I should inflate another view. is that so?

Comment: if I am correct, you have 1 receiver view and 1 sender view for every message! And you are just hiding them. So you have 2*view that you suppose to have. Am I correct?

Comment: I have one layout xml file with LinearLayouts in it. 1st- SenderView with only text. 2nd- Sender with Image View. 3rd- Sender with Video View. 4th- ReceiverView with only text. 5th- ReceiverView with Image View. 6th- ReceiverView with Video View. And i am making them visible and gone on the basis of conditions.

Comment: that's even worse than I thought. please update your code with the Chat_Holder and everything else that you think it is relevant

Comment: go with the 2nd approach

Comment: can you post the whole of your adapter class?

Comment: Thank you gmetax for your guidelines. It really worked and now the list is smooth like never before..